# Inherit static methods

Tags: php, oop

I have the following problem; there are 2 models in my application, but they are stored in the same table in my database. They can be differentiated by their `type` column, the first being 0 and the second 1.

In my application i've made 2 classes, one for each type. However i'd only want to create the queries once, and use a static member to figure out the type. Basicly what i want to achieve would look like this:

```
class A
{
    public $Description; //From the database

    public static function GetAll()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = " . self::getType();

        echo $query;
    }

    private static function getType()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class B
    extends A
{
    public $SomeOtherProperty; //B also has another property, which A doesnt have. Its stored an another table.

    private static function getType()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

A::GetAll(10);
B::GetAll(10);
```

However, PHP doesnt support static memberwriting, which results in this output:

> SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = 0
>
> SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = 0

What's the best way to achieve such a result, where the child-class can specify its own type?

Comment: Not a real answer, but you should avoid using static classes like this. PHP's static calls are basically a way to group related functions, not to use inheritance and other oop related techniques.

Comment: The class isnt static on itself, A has all the properties of the model. However the method to get all A's in the database is static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use **protected** visibility when you inherit the method getType():

```
protected static function getType();
```

And for getting current type, use PHP 5.3 new feature of **static** keyword: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = " . static::getType();
```

Static ensures the late binding will be used so the method of actual type will be used.

Comment: Ah, so this is the new `late static binding` feature. Thanks a bunch, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

If you use php >= 5.3 you can use the **static** keyword :

```
public static function GetAll()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = " . static::getType();

    echo $query;
}
```

If you don't, you can pass another parameter to the GetAll() method to provide the type :

```
public static function GetAll($type)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM letters WHERE type = " . $type;

    echo $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try and use a static variable in the classes, representing `$type`. you can overwrite static vars as far as i know.

This should wotk for php>5.3. In php 5.2 it works as you describe in the comments

Comment: I've tried this, and it didnt work. The value of the current instance of the class (A) is used when you call a method on the base class.